# Should hasClass precede removeClass - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Is it necessary to check if a class exists before I use the `removeClass` api on an jquery object?
eg.

```
if($(this).hasClass("test"))
   $(this).removeClass("test");
```

or

```
$(this).removeClass("test");
```

if not necessary, why so?

Comment: Have you tried if it works either way? Did it?

Comment: well jquery avoids throwing error in most cases and yea it works

Comment: Since it works and produces no errors, apparently it is not necessary. You should not try to second-guess exception handling in third party code — if it does not let an exception escape uncaught, then it has been handled.

Answer (score 39):

Use just this:

```
$(this).removeClass("test");
```

There is no need to check for class existence.

From [jQuery sources](http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js) we can see that `removeClass` method uses [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method to remove the substring:

```
className = (" " + elem.className + " ").replace(rclass, " ");
for (c = 0, cl = classNames.length; c < cl; c++) {
    className = className.replace(" " + classNames[c] + " ", " ");
}​
```

And `replace` won't remove anything if the matching substring does not exist.

Comment: The `hasClass` may not be needed for correct functionality but some quick testing shows that is faster to check first (at least for me on three different browsers) - https://jsfiddle.net/trevorpower/5mu7shg1/2/

Answer (score 6):

At least for Chrome, it is useful to add a hasClass() check before removeClass(), because jQuery unconditionally assigns elem.className to the new string even if the string hasn't changed, which causes Chrome to invalidate and recalculate the layout.

One could argue that this is a bug in Chrome and it should check whether the className has actually changed from the previous value. However, it could also be that the browser *has* to recalculate the layout due to some obscure requirements that are written somewhere deep in the html spec.

I haven't tested Firefox. The Safari web inspector is useless as it won't tell you why the layout was invalidated/recalculated (which javascript function caused it).

Comment: Is this still valid for Chrome?

Answer (score 3):

No, not necessary to check for `removeClass()`.

Just use

```
   $(this).removeClass("test");
```