# Should I check if a class exists before I attempt to remove it with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I have:

```
function myFunction() {

    $("body").removeClass("toggled");
}
$(window).on('resize',myFunction);
```

It seems to work. But... I don't know... It seems a bit short? :P

Are there any performance penalties by doing it like this? I can imagine JQuery secretly throwing errors every time this class couldn't be found (but I might be talking nonsense).

A little clarification would be helpful :)

Best regards,

Michael

Comment: This is correct. You would increase overhead if you checked for the class before removing it. This seems short because it is. It's where jQuery shines

Comment: Actually this question has been asked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895631/should-hasclass-precede-removeclass-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't worry. As far as I know jQuery checks if the classes are available itself.

But you could also remove classes like this:

```
$('body.toggled').removeClass('toggled');
```

so `removeClass()` isn't called if there is no `toggled` class on the body.

Answer (score 0):

Just so it can be marked as an answer:

No it doesn't matter if the class is there or not.  No errors will be thrown.

Comment: but whyyyyyyyyy

Answer (score 0):

No you dont have to check that. Their wont be any error if the element does not have class which you want to remove.