# Inherit this to function

Tags: javascript, jquery, this

I want to change it by use functions which runs on click to write it more clearly. This is code which works:

```
    menuHamburger.click(function () {

        if($(this).hasClass("closed")){
            $(this).removeClass("closed");
        };
        subMenu.removeClass("show");

        if (mainSidebar.toggleClass('active')) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

I would like to write it in this way:

```
    menuHamburger.click(function () {

        closedHamburderOnClick();

        if($(this).hasClass("closed")){
            $(this).removeClass("closed");
        };
        subMenu.removeClass("show");

        if (mainSidebar.toggleClass('active')) {
            return true;
        }
    });


    function closedHamburderOnClick(){
        if($(this).hasClass("closed")){
            $(this).removeClass("closed");
        };
    }
```

but it doesn't work. How to fix it?

Comment: You can pass `$(this)` as a function parameter just like any other.

Comment: You don't have to test if an element has a class to remove it. Just do `$(this).removeClass("closed show");`

Comment: Something tells me there are several lines in your second code block you meant to delete.

Comment: You can use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) i.e. `closedHamburderOnClick.call(this)`

Comment: What is the error you get? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: It looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10895631/should-hasclass-precede-removeclass-jquery

Comment: @DenysSéguret, I don't think that OP is focused on `hasClass`

Comment: Just FWIW, it's "hamburger" (with a "g"), not "hamburder" (with a "d"). The rest of that function name is in English, so I'm assuming it's a typo rather than a different language...

Comment: Hamburder...mmmmm.  I'm hundry now!

Answer (score 0):

In this particular case, just pass `$(this)` into your function and declare a parameter to use:

```
menuHamburger.click(function () {

    closedHamburderOnClick($(this));

    // (removed lines here I'm fairly sure you meant to remove in the question)

    subMenu.removeClass("show");

    if (mainSidebar.toggleClass('active')) {
        return true;
    }
});


function closedHamburderOnClick(elements){
    if(elements.hasClass("closed")){         // You can get rid of this entirely
        elements.removeClass("closed");
    } // No ; after the block attached to control flow statements
}
```

**If** you had some reason you needed to call `closedHamburderOnClick` so that `this` within it refers to the same thing as it does when you make the call, you'd use [`Function#call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

```
closedHamburderOnClick.call(this);
```

and then use `this` within it:

```
function closedHamburderOnClick(){
    if($(this).hasClass("closed")){         // You can get rid of this entirely
        $(this).removeClass("closed");
    } // No ; after the block attached to control flow statements
}
```

There's also [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which also handles `this` the same way, but `call` and `apply` handle arguments differently.

But there's no need for `call` or `apply` in this case.